# What does #ifdef 1 in C++

Tags: c++, macros, c-preprocessor, conditional-compilation, preprocessor-directive

in C++, I know that programmers use `#ifdef 0` to block out code from running, but in this same project I see a lot of `#ifdef 1`. Does this mean that the code always runs? Unfortunately the code does not compile so I can't just run and test!

Comment: Did you misread the code? Does it in fact say `#if 0` and `#if 1`?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`#ifdef 1` is ill-formed.  The `#ifdef` directive requires a single identifier; `1` is not an identifier.

`#ifdef x` is equivalent to `#if defined(x)`.  The `defined` preprocessing operator yields `true` if the identifier names a defined macro (i.e., a macro that has been defined with `#define` and not yet undefined via `#undef`) and `false` otherwise.

The `#if` directive enables or disables compilation of the lines between it and the corresponding `#else`, `#elif`, or `#endif` directive that follows it (the directives nest).

Chances are, what you are really looking for is `#if 1` (or `#if 0`), which is valid.

Comment: Says everything one could want except that 1 in `#if 1` is also considered true and enables compilation accordingly, while the 0 in `#if 0` is false....